# Ignoring spacing in commands

Tags: fractions

I am using `setspace`, `\spacing`. I have many functions which are making arrays and when i have `\begin{spacing} {1.5}` i am getting spacing in those special functions, w
\documentclass{article}

```
\usepackage{cancel,amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\newcommand{\stackBelowCancel}[2]{\begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}\cancel{#1}\\#2\end{array}} % stacking BELOW canceling number(NOT FRACTION)


\begin{document}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{spacing}{1.5}
        1.  $\dfrac{1}{3\cancel{0}}\cdot\dfrac{1\cancel{0}}{\stackBelowCancel{27}{3}}=\dfrac{1}{9}$ (Have spacing)
        \end{spacing}
        2. $\dfrac{1}{3\cancel{0}}\cdot\dfrac{1\cancel{0}}{\stackBelowCancel{27}{3}}=\dfrac{1}{9}$ (Not in spacing)
    \end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

I want to achieve the look from the second **line(2.)** in the spacing environment. How to ignore this  spacing which I have in line 1, in the command? 
[image]

Comment: Off topic, but shouldn't it equal 1/81?

Comment: Yes there is a mistake, instead 1/30 it's 3/30.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a general problem with `array` along with `setspace` and can be cured by resetting `\arraystretch` to counteract `\baselinestretch`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel,amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xfp}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\setstretch}[1]{%
  \def\baselinestretch{#1}\@currsize
  \edef\arraystretch{\fpeval{1/(#1)}}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\stackBelowCancel}[2]{%
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}\cancel{#1}\\#2\end{array}%
} % stacking BELOW canceling number(NOT FRACTION)

\begin{document}

\begin{spacing}{1.5}
1.  $\dfrac{1}{3\cancel{0}}\cdot\dfrac{1\cancel{0}}{\stackBelowCancel{27}{3}}=
\dfrac{1}{9}$ (Have spacing)
\end{spacing}

\begin{doublespacing}
2. $\dfrac{1}{3\cancel{0}}\cdot\dfrac{1\cancel{0}}{\stackBelowCancel{27}{3}}=
\dfrac{1}{9}$ (Have spacing)
\end{doublespacing}

3. $\dfrac{1}{3\cancel{0}}\cdot\dfrac{1\cancel{0}}{\stackBelowCancel{27}{3}}=
\dfrac{1}{9}$ (Not in spacing)

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, those simplifications are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Forget `array`...just `\stackunder`.  Note the default is text mode stacking.  If you want math mode, the declaration `\stackMath` in the preamble will do that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel,amsmath,stackengine}
\usepackage{setspace}
\newcommand{\stackBelowCancel}[2]{\stackunder[4pt]{\cancel{#1}}{#2}} % stacking BELOW canceling number(NOT FRACTION)


\begin{document}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{spacing}{1.5}
        1.  $\dfrac{1}{3\cancel{0}}\cdot\dfrac{1\cancel{0}}{\stackBelowCancel{27}{3}}=\dfrac{1}{9}$ (Have spacing)
        \end{spacing}
        2. $\dfrac{1}{3\cancel{0}}\cdot\dfrac{1\cancel{0}}{\stackBelowCancel{27}{3}}=\dfrac{1}{9}$ (Not in spacing)
    \end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use `\underset` instead of an `array`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel,amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}

% always textstyle
\newcommand{\stackBelowCancel}[2]{\underset{\textstyle#2}{\cancel{#1}}}

% adapt to outer style
%\newcommand{\stackBelowCancel}[2]{\mathpalette\dostackBelowCancel{{#1}{#2}}}
%\newcommand{\dostackBelowCancel}[2]{\dostackBelowCancelIndeed{#1}#2}
%\newcommand{\dostackBelowCancelIndeed}[3]{\underset{#1#3}{\cancel{#2}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{spacing}{1.5}
        1.  $\dfrac{1}{3\cancel{0}}\cdot\dfrac{1\cancel{0}}{\stackBelowCancel{27}{3}}=\dfrac{1}{9}$ (Have spacing)
        \end{spacing}
        2. $\dfrac{1}{3\cancel{0}}\cdot\dfrac{1\cancel{0}}{\stackBelowCancel{27}{3}}=\dfrac{1}{9}$ (Not in spacing)
    \end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good, but is there anyway to make the number in underset bigger? Like in the example.

Comment: @SimeonSimeonov I have added two solutions to the answer.  You can either always use `\textstyle` or you can adapt to the surrounding math style.  The latter one is commented out.